# Does the notion of people being in temporary non-sacred or polluted status exist outside the South?

Tags: practice, customs

Reasons could be things like a death in the family, women having their period.

Does this come from scripture and is it practiced outside the South today?

Comment: yes, asaucha is there in the smritis and in sraaddha mantras.In Bengal the custom is there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those periods, when impurities prevail due to birth or death that occurred in a family, are called the *Asaucha* period and it is a scriptural thing so all Hindus irrespective of the region they belong to must follow those rules.

Birth/death related impurities are called Jataka/Mritaka Asaucha.

> 1. **Now I shall speak of the term of impurity resulting on the occurrence of a birth, or a death.** Brahmans in three days become
>      pure again, when a relative has died, or has been born.
> 2. A Kshatriya recovers purity in twelve days ; a Vaisya, when fifteen days have passed ; a Shoodra, after the lapse of a month ; this is
>      conformable to what Parasara has said.
>
> **Parashara Smriti, 3rd Chapter**

Answer (score 2):

Asaucha is the word and it comes of Asuchi which means impurity :[http://sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=अशुच](http://sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%9A)ि&lang=sans&action=Search

In the sraddha-mantra, it is mentioned that the sraddha has to be done "asauchantyaat dwitiye ahni" meaning on the second day of ending of Asaucha. So Asaucha is a must for sraddha karma in hindu culture.

As Rickross points out,the period of Asaucha varies from castse to caste. Many mentioning a comment of Sataatapa, opine that ten days asauchaa is precribed by Sataatapa.But this prescription is not found in Satatapa-Smriti, as per Sri Sitaramdas Omkarnath(Omkarnath Rachanavali, vol 7)